# Get index of an array

Tags: php

I'm having some problems retrieving data from a multidimensional array. I have something like this:

```
$Act[0] = array(
"Number" => 23,
"Local" => "woods",
"props" => "swords..."
.....

$Act[1] = array(
"Number" => 27,
"Local" => "castle",
"props" => "swords..."
.....
......

$Story[$day] = array(
                  "Date" => $SDate,
                  "Acts" => $Acts
                  );
```

What I want to do is to get all the numbers from the Act array and use implode to store it in a mysql db.
I tried array_keys but it doesnt work with multi-dimensional arrays. I dont know if it would be even appropriate for this. So basically I want an array with all the values of "Number" of $Story[1]["Acts"], so it would have to go through:

```
$Story[1]["Act"][0]["Number"]
$Story[1]["Act"][1]["Number"]
$Story[1]["Act"][2]["Number"]
...
```

Comment: 1. `foreach` 2. "and use implode to store it in a mysql db" --- this might be the worst idea ever

Comment: It was a typo, this is sort of pseudo-code. It is Act

Comment: Those specific values that will be "imploded" are not used for querying the db. Is that why it would be a bad idea?
Just trying to get an array like (23, 27, ...., ....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So...

```
$numbers = array_map(function($act) {
    return $act["Number"];
}, $Story[1]["Acts"]);

# 23, 27, ...
```

Is that what you're asking?